# $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\log x}(x^{\alpha} - x^{\beta})$ again?

Tags: integration

I have been looking at the answers to the question - what is the value of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\log x}(x^{\alpha} - x^{\beta})$. 
My question is, what has driven the questioners to seek the solution of the integral? I ask because I have been attempting some historical research on a paper of Euler - 'Analytical Speculations' where he uses this integral as a starting point to derive some other associated results. He produced a solution to this problem which is typically Eulerian.

First set $x^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha \log x}$. 
Use the series expansion for $e^{z}$ where $z = \alpha \log x $. Adopt a similar expansion for $x^{\beta}$.

As an aside, he develops the result that $ \int_{0}^{1} (log x)^{n} dx = \pm n! $ positive when n is even, negative when odd.

Substituting the two series into the integral leads him to

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\log x}((x^{\alpha} - x^{\beta}) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\log x}((1 + \alpha \log x + \frac{\alpha^{2} \log^{2} x}{1.2} + \frac{\alpha^{3} \log^{3} x}{1.2.3} + etc.) - (1 + \beta \log x + \frac{\beta^{2} \log^{2} x}{1.2} + \frac{\beta^{3} \log^{3} x}{1.2.3} + etc.)) $

which, integrating term by termsusing the above integral result, simplifies to

$(\alpha - \beta) - \frac{(\alpha^{2} - \beta^{2})}{2} + \frac{(\alpha^{3} - \beta^{3})}{3} - \frac{(\alpha^{4} - \beta^{4})}{4} +etc.$ which is the series for $\log(1 + \alpha) = \log(1 + \beta) = \log\frac{\alpha + 1}{\beta + 1}$.

As an additional 'extra', for little effort, he sets $\alpha = \alpha - 1$ and $\beta = \beta - 1$ in the original integral to derive
$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\log x}(x^{\alpha - 1} - x^{\beta - 1}) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x\log x}(x^{\alpha} - x^{\beta}) = \log\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$.

Comment: Could you give at least one reference where you have seen this formula ?

Comment: In http://eulerarchive.maa.org/, Index number 475.

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't about the solution, more about where the problem arose. Euler uses it as a jumping off point for a number of integrals, e.g. choosing $\alpha = \sqrt{-1}n$ and $\beta = 1\sqrt{-1}n$ leads him to explore $\int \frac{dx\sin n\log x}{\log x} $.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ \left(\alpha,\beta\right)\in\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right)^{2} $, using the fact that $ \int_{\beta}^{\alpha}{x^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\left[\frac{x^{y}}{\ln{x}}\right]_{\beta}^{\alpha}=\frac{x^{\alpha}-x^{\beta}}{\ln{x}} $, then using Fubini's theorem, we get :

$$ \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{\alpha}-x^{\beta}}{\ln{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{\beta}^{\alpha}{x^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{\beta}^{\alpha}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{y}\,\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\int_{\beta}^{\alpha}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y}}=\ln{\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1+\beta}\right)} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : perform the substitution $x=e^t$ and another substitution and finally use [the frullani's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral)

Does it answer your question? otherwise I delete

Answer (score 0):

Let $I(t)= \int_0^1 \frac {x^t}{\ln x}dx$. Then,

$$I’(t)=  \int_0^1 {x^t}dx =\frac1{1+t}$$

Then,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{\alpha} - x^{\beta}}{\ln x}dx=I(\alpha)-I(\beta)= \int_{\beta}^{\alpha} I’(t)dt= 
\int_{\beta}^{\alpha} \frac{dt}{1+t}= \ln\frac{1+\alpha}{1+\beta} $$